# How to check if the environment variable "PROJ_LIB" is defined and how to unset it ? (PyQGIS Standalone Script Executer)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, osgeo, pyqgis

I just tried the standalone PyQGIS application by running the custom script  "Proximity.py"* in a VS Code project without the need of a GUI (such as QGIS).

But, when I run the python-program I get the following message:

***proj_create_from_database: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\share\contrib\postgis-3.2\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 0 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.*** (see also: [Error Message after launching the configuration (launch.json) from VS Code (when pressing F5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHB2L.png))

I'm trying this online example with the following installations:

- PostgreSQL 14
- Python39
- .vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher
- [osgeo4w-setup.exe](https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v2/) (including QGIS LTR)

I read that there is a solution by undefining [PROJ_LIB] before importing pyproj or osgeo: **del os.environ ['PROJ_LIB']** [as described under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460405/gdal-in-virtual-environment-vs-postgressql-11). If this is also supposed to be the correct solution in this case, can someone help me with step-by-step instructions (for dummies)?

*. * The "Proximity.py" script is a pyqgis standalone example from "https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone"*

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got a solution to be able to run the "standalone PyQGIS"* example ["Proximity"](https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone)  (*provided by MarByteBeep*).

This solution was possible without needing to launch the configuration file "[launch.json](https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone/blob/main/.vscode/launch.json)" as above described. And so, avoiding the need to make any configuration to the environment variable "PROJ_LIB" by trying to circumvent the above issue.

I just first added the following two code-lines (see here line **2 and 3**) in the python file ["main.py"](https://github.com/MarByteBeep/pyqgis-standalone/blob/main/main.py) so as to be able to use the plugin "PROCESSING" (initially line 8 of the "main.py" file), then I store it and finally I ran it.

*Line 1: from qgis.core import*

**Line 2: import sys

Line 3: sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.1\apps\qgis\python\plugins')**

*Line 4: qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

Line 5: ...*

The Proximity example is based on the answer of "Mar Tjin" to the following Question: ["Looking for manual on how to properly setup standalone PyQGIS without GUI"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421362/looking-for-manual-on-how-to-properly-setup-standalone-pyqgis-without-gui)

*. * By "Standalone PyQGIS" I refer to code/scripts that can be run outside the QGIS-GUI (=> QGIS-Desktop/Server Application). In my case under the external Editor VS Code*